# GODOT update gravity in realtime

Tags: physics, godot, gravity

Trying to align the in game physics with devide gravity in realtime.
Inspired by "[How to change global gravity properties at runtime?](https://godotengine.org/qa/1290/how-to-change-global-gravity-properties-at-runtime#:%7E:text=How%20to%20change%20global%20gravity%20properties%20at%20runtime%3F)" post using following code during _process/_physics_process

```
    var acc_gravity = Input.get_gravity().rotated(Vector3(-1, 0, 0), deg2rad(90))
    PhysicsServer.area_set_param(get_world().get('space'),
        PhysicsServer.AREA_PARAM_GRAVITY_VECTOR, acc_gravity.normalized())
    PhysicsServer.area_set_param(get_world().get('space'),
        PhysicsServer.AREA_PARAM_GRAVITY, acc_gravity.length())
```

But the physics just went into very weird behavior, kind of slowmotion or outright nothing move. Seems these parameter setting does much more than changing a number; and can only be set at ready but not updated constantly. Is there a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand you want a constantly changing gravity. I suggest to not use gravity at all. Instead simply use `add_central_force` in `_physics_process`:

```
add_central_force(Input.get_gravity().rotated(Vector3(-1, 0, 0), deg2rad(90)))
```

---

This is something that differs between 2D and 3D physics in Godot: in 3D forces are reset every physics frame.

So, if I do this in a `RigidBody2D`:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    add_central_force(Vector2.LEFT * 10)
```

I'll see the `RigidBody2D` accelerate to the left…

But if I do this in a `RigidBody`:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    add_central_force(Vector3.LEFT * 10)
```

I'll see the `RigidBody` move a little and then stop, or not move at all (depending if it is using Bullet or GodotPhysics).

---

Thus, since you are working in 3D, you don't need to keep track of the prior forces you added.